Set transparent SDL window background
Having the following simple PNG image rendering example:
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <iostream>

char g_buffer[100];

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hThisInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR str, int nWinMode) {

    SDL_Event event;
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = NULL;
    SDL_Texture* texture = NULL;
    SDL_Texture* texture2 = NULL;
    SDL_Window* window = NULL;

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_TIMER | SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer(
        400, 400,
        0, &window, &renderer
    );

    IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG);

    texture = IMG_LoadTexture(renderer, "D:/Pobrane_2/flower.png");
    if (!texture)
    {
        sprintf(g_buffer, "IMG_LoadTexture error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        MessageBox(NULL, g_buffer, "Error!", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        g_buffer[0] = 0;
        return 1;
    }

    while (1) {
        // Select the color for drawing. It is set to red here.
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 0, 0, 255);
        // Clear the entire screen to our selected color.
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, NULL);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
        if (SDL_PollEvent(&event) && event.type == SDL_QUIT)
            break;
    }
    SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
    IMG_Quit();
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

How can one make the window background color transparent instead of solid red just to see what's behind the app window (for e.g. windows desktop)? I'd prefer platform independent code if possible.
Note: this is not a duplicate of my previous question: Making window background transparent

SDL does not support per-pixel alpha transparency on a window.

And there are no plans to include this functionality either (see here). You'll have to write platform-specific code if you need this functionality. There are many Q&A's here that explain how to do that on Windows.

Alternatively and as a shortcut, for the entire window you can set SDL_SetWindowOpacity(SDL_window* window, float opacity).
